# Nginx configuration resulting in too many connections

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

In an attempt to implement the [upload progress module](https://github.com/masterzen/nginx-upload-progress-module/), the following server configuration is resulting in **too many open files** error

```
2014/11/19 12:10:34 [alert] 31761#0: *1010 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: xxx, request: "GET /documents/15/edit HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/documents/15/edit", host: "127.0.0.1"
2014/11/19 12:10:34 [crit] 31761#0: *1010 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (24: Too many open files), client: 127.0.0.1, server: xxx, request: "GET /documents/15/edit HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/documents/15/edit", host: "127.0.0.1"
```

The following is the relevant part of the server bloc which is generating the conflict
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env    development;
        root         /home/user/app/current/public;

```
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    location / {
        # proxy to upstream server
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_redirect default;

        # track uploads in the 'proxied' zone
        # remember connections for 30s after they finished
        track_uploads proxied 30s;
    }

    location ^~ /progress {
        # report uploads tracked in the 'proxied' zone
        report_uploads proxied;
    }
```

Being a relative n00b to nginx, I do not comprehend where this is generating the too many files error.  I assumed that the error pages are only for 500-504 server errors...

Answer (score 5):

First check and increase open files limit in the root shell (system-wide, it is 1024 usually):

```
# ulimit -n
# ulimit -n 16384
```

Then you can increase nginx's open files limit (main context, top of nginx.conf):

```
worker_rlimit_nofile 16384
```

Then restart nginx )

If this not help, check more detail solutions like

[Nginx: 24: Too Many Open Files Error And Solution](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-too-many-open-files/)

Comment: There appears to be some relationship with the `worker_connections` defined at events level.  Because I'm getting `8192 worker_connections are not enough`  That figure I am pluggin in by trial and error, but resulting in either `too many files` or insufficient worker_conncetions errors.  The link suggests system wide limits.  I may try that, but again is there a relationship between hard and soft limits?