# How to determine server is nearing full potential load

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

My server running php / mysql has had issues resulting in thousands of 502 bad gateway errors per minute during peak hours.

**Server configuration is**

- Dedicated server
- 24v cores
- 120GB ram
- 1.5TB hdd

First fix was switching from Fastcgi to Nginx.

Second fix a while later was adding a few more indexes into database and code optimization.

A while later again during peak hours, several thousand of connections end in 502 bad gateway while connections that **do not** end up in 502 error, are fast and smooth.

My error log is filled with following:

```
 1708#0: *66048341 connect() to unix:***/php-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream

[alert] 1708#0: *66066227 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream
```

During peak hours, phpmyadmin shows tops 20% CPU load and 50% ram usage.

So the question is, how to detect weak spots in code and poor index usage? How to determine that a server is reaching full potential load?

Comment: how many connection are concurrent on the system

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx configuration resulting in too many connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015687/nginx-configuration-resulting-in-too-many-connections)

Comment: Might also be helpful: https://gist.github.com/joewiz/4c39c9d061cf608cb62b

Comment: @BerndBuffen during peak hours phpmyadmin shows 300 connections per second (taken from graph data)